# How to get only characters from a file in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a file txt. This is the file:

```
    Team            P     W    L   D    F      A     Pts
1. Arsenal         38    26   9   3    79  -  36    87
2. Liverpool       38    24   8   6    67  -  30    80
3. Manchester_U    38    24   5   9    87  -  45    77
4. Newcastle       38    21   8   9    74  -  52    71
5. Leeds           38    18  12   8    53  -  37    66
6. Chelsea         38    17  13   8    66  -  38    64
7. West_Ham        38    15   8  15    48  -  57    53
8. Aston_Villa     38    12  14  12    46  -  47    50
9. Tottenham       38    14   8  16    49  -  53    50
```

How can I get only the name of teams? I tried to use the regex in the following way but don't work:

```
FileReader f;
f=new FileReader("file.txt");
         BufferedReader b;
         b=new BufferedReader(f);
s=b.readLine(); 
String[] name = s.split("\\w+");
             for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
             System.out.println(name[i]);
```

How do I solve? Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: what does your code do? Does it not work, what is the output you receive right now?

Comment: use '\\[a-zA-Z]+" , it should be worked.. :)

Comment: @luk2302 My code works. I added only the important things for the sake of brevity. in any way, my output is this:     
. 
         
    
   
   
    
  -  
    
    
. 
       
    
   
   
    
  -  
    
    
. 
    
    
   
   
    
  -  
    
    
. 
       
    
   
   
    
  -  
    
    
. 
           
    
  
   
    
  -  
    
    
.

Comment: @Amit Already tried. If I use \[a-zA-Z]+ my output is all the file and not only the name of teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FileReader f;
f=new FileReader("file.txt");
     BufferedReader b;
     b=new BufferedReader(f);
while(s=b.readLine()!=null){
     Matcher name=Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d\\.\\s)\\S+").matcher(s);   
     if(name.find())
           System.out.println(name.group());
 }
```

here the regex `(?<=\\d\\.\\s)\\S+` will match only the name after the serial no.  [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/BjF2td/1)

Comment: This works. Thanks my friend! ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `replaceAll`, find all word characters (`a-zA-Z_`) and replace them all with empty. this gives team name.

```
s=b.readLine();
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_]+","");
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read line by line and your file has structure as you presented. These code enable you to get clubs names.

```
File f = new File("file.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
sc.nextLine();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] name = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(name[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string `s` is one line:

```
1. Arsenal         38    26   9   3    79  -  36    87
```

All you need to do is split by space and get second entry:

```
s.split(" ")[1]
```

RegEx is overkill here. Do this for each line and add the name to a list at each step.

Comment: what if `2.Liverpool       38    24   8   6    67  -  30    80` ? it can happen in text files